# Javascript tile map. (With emojis)

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to make a code that can generate maps. I tried this:

```
      var mapArray = [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 1],
    ];
    
    function drawMap() {  
        let map = "";
        for (var y = 0; y < mapArray.length; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < mapArray[y].length; x++) {
                if (parseInt(mapArray[y][x]) == 0) {
                  var title = map.concat("⬛");
                }
                if (parseInt(mapArray[y][x]) == 1) {
                  var title = map.concat("⬜");
                }
                if (parseInt(mapArray[y][x]) == 2) {
                  var title = map.concat("");
                }
                if (parseInt(mapArray[y][x]) == 3) {
                  var title = map.concat("");
                }
                title.x = x * 28;
                title.y = y * 28;
                console.log(map)
                return map;
            }
        }
    }   
    drawMap()
```

I tried this code but it logged empty. Then I tried to move `console.log(map)` to end of the function and it logged empty again.

Answer (score 0):

first, you can iterate through array with `.map()` function, my guess you trying to do so

Second, your `if` approach is not really scalable
you will need to write more `if` statements when new numbers goona be in your map (4, 5, 6 for example)

Combination of these two:

```
// dictionary for storing number:image pair
const dictionary = {
  0: "⬛",
  1: "⬜",
  2: "",
  3: ""
}

// function arguments is array and tictionary
function transformArray(arr, dict) {
  // iterating through every `insideArray` in `arr`
  return arr.map(insideArray => {
    // iterating through every `item` in `insideArray`
    return insideArray.map(item => {
      // trying to lookup image in dictionary
      // if there is no `item` key - return default value ""
      return dict[item] || ""
    })
  })
}

const tranfsormedArray = transformArray(mapArray, dictionary)

console.log(transformedArray)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. How can I combine these?

Comment: what exacly you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand how can I combine these. I'm not good at mapping.